# A Rattling Tale

Tags: story, language

<sub><sup>(I apologise for the length of this story and poor formatting of the dialogue. There are some pretty long questions at /questions/tagged/story, so I figured they are not banned. If you feel it is too long, you can probably figure out the answer by reading the blockquotes and instructions alone)</sup></sub>

---

My work environment had been exceptionally toxic today, so when I got home I just took a quick nap and went straight to the pub. I was sitting on a corner, drinking beer alone, when I noticed an old friend of mine from high school walking towards me.

This guy, a girl and I used to be really close, but we all went our separate ways after school.
He went to college to study linguistics or something like that, the girl got a job at a software company and I took over my dad's business.
He sat next to me and struck up a conversation.

> Roamin' around and who do I find? You lookin' sharp, Bob. Did you come here straight from work?

---

> Astray like a lost sheep, yet he returns! Good ole mr. Blake! Actually I did. How's college going, Joe?

---

> Amazing. But there's something I need to talk with you about. Do you remember our friend Ana, kinda tall and pale?

---

> Yeah. In the end, professional career choices put us at odds with one another, but of course I remember her. She was a real charm, that one. What about her?

---

> Hell, lean back and get a cup of coffee, the absurd story I want to tell you will make more sense if you are sober.

---

> Just report it, geezer. Is it a good one?

---

> Thanks for lettin' me share it. Actually it's been creeping me out, I bet you'll be unnerved too...
>
> ... Nah, what'll scare you is what happened after she left her job at Loco Atlanta Corporation.
>
> She was not exactly a patron of hard work, but it looked like she loved that job. She was always bragging about this "something-dot-net" she used.
>
> Oh, and this "delphi" and "pylon" things they used at the office.
>
> Or so I thought. Well, she reached the nadir of her mental health about a month ago.
>
> Did you panic yet, Bob? Get this: she started talking about going on a trip to find the African Heavy

---

> African Heavy? Is that some kind of slang?

---

> What her goal was is beyond me. Anyway, she even bought khaki shorts and leather shoes for the trip.
>
> Amanda, her in-law, didn't have a clue either. Was she too fed up with work?

---

> A rabid work environment can make you go nuts. That had been a problem when she was a teen.

---

> OK, I'll just spit it out. She ended up travelling to Mexico, brother, and she died there. Ana is dead.
>
> Two days had already elapsed before I was able to get to the village where she was, and her name had already been added to the obituary.
>
> I checked it myself. She HAD been declared dead. But yesterday I saw her outside my window at night. And this morning following me in the subway.
>
> The cops are headed to my house right now. I can't illustrate how terrified I am Bobby. Am I going crazy Bobby? Bobby? Bobby? Bobby?

"Bobby?"

I woke up on my couch. I hadn't really gone to the pub, I was still napping. What the hell was that eerie nightmare?

"Bobby?"

Was that Ana calling my name? Maybe I hadn't fully woken up. As my vision cleared, I think I saw Ana standing in front of me. She was wearing something thick on her right arm.

"Wakey wakey"

There must have been something on my mind to explain my dream. Maybe it was something I was hearing as I slept. **What could it be?**

"You're one slippery chap, I'll give you that."

And then it struck me.

---

## Hints and instructions

This story has 20 lines of dialogue. **Each line has a pair of clues embodying a concept that is related to the "final" answer**. In some lines, the first clue helps you interpret the second one, in other lines, the two clues have to be interpreted together.

Some lines are easier to figure out than others. In fact, finding the final answer is probably much easier than finding all 20 clues. For this reason, the "clues" are part of the answer, so **your answer must get at least 16/20 clues right** in addition to the "final" answer before it is accepted. I'll let you know if your final answer is right, though.

The backstory and metadata contain some clues too, but these do not count towards the 20. Good luck!

---

<s>Extra hints</s> Fun facts not related to the puzzle at all:

> - An eastern company has launched this new perfume, Yod Cole Essence. You should try using it.
> - It is often said that a certain people named themselves after a kidnapped princess, but that is not true.
> - There are many dangerous creatures in the Empty Quarter. More than one, that's for sure.
> - Autumn leaves have a rather cupreous appearance down south. Good for certain fans of Crypsis, I guess. If you plan on going there, I heard the natives can help you find adequate clothes and footwear.

Comment: The last section makes it clear that you require that 16 of the 20 clues are solved. Do you still encourage partial solutions? I think I've got 12 of the clues and the final answer, but this is getting tough and I think solving could benefit from a community effort.

Comment: @MOehm Absolutely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My dream was about ...

> ... a **snake**.
>
>  The lines of dialogue contain types of snakes or the [words for snake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snake) in other languages, where the language in question is hidden somewhere on the same line. The "slippery chap" at the end is a hint towards reptiles, as is the title, which alludes to rattlesnakes.
>
>  The thick thing Ana is wearing could be a snake that coils around her arm. There are several interpretations of what dreaming of a snake means.

I haven't got answers to all twenty clues yet. Here's what I have:

(1) Roamin' around and who do I find? You lookin' sharp, Bob. Did you come here straight from work?

> "Șarpe", sounds like sharp, is snake in Romanian ("Roamin'")

(2) Astray like a lost sheep, yet he returns! Good ole Mr. Blake! Actually I did. How's college going, Joe?

> "Joe Blake" is Australian ("Astray like"?) rhyming slang for a snake.

(3) Amazing. But there's something I need to talk with you about. Do you remember our friend Ana, kinda tall and pale?

> "Anaconda" sounds (a bit) like "Ana kinda" and anacondas live near the Amazon ("amazing"?) river.

(4) Yeah. In the end, professional career choices put us at odds with one another, but of course I remember her. She was a real charm, that one. What about her?

> Snake charmers are Indian professionals (sounds like "In the end, professional").

(5) Hell, lean back and get a cup of coffee, the absurd story I want to tell you will make more sense if you are sober.

> —

(6) Just report it, geezer. Is it a good one?

> In Portuguese (as heard in "report it geezer"), one of the words for good is "boa", which is also the name of a snake.

(7) Thanks for lettin' me share it. Actually it's been creeping me out, I bet you'll be unnerved too...

> The last part refers to anguish and "Anguis" is snake in Latin ("Lettin'")

(8) ... Nah, what'll scare you is what happened after she left her job at Loco Atlanta Corporation.

> "Coatl", the Aztec/Nahuatl ("Nah, what'll") word for snake, is hidden in "Lo(co Atl)anta".

(9) She was not exactly a patron of hard work, but it looked like she loved that job. She was always bragging about this "something-dot-net" she used.

> The something-dot-net is "ASP.NET". Cleopatra, whose name is hidden in "exactly a patron" when spoken, committed suicide by allowing herself to be bitten by an asp.

(10) Oh, and this "delphi" and "pylon" things they used at the office.

> The programming language is, of course, "Python" and not pylon. And "ophis", which sounds like office, is snake in ancient Greek as spoken in Delphi, perhaps by the priestess Pythia.

(11) Or so I thought. Well, she reached the nadir of her mental health about a month ago.

> "Neidr" is Welsh ("Well, she") for snake and it sounds like nadir. (Thanks, Timoris!)

(12) Did you panic yet, Bob? Get this: she started talking about going on a trip to find the African Heavy

> —

(13) African Heavy? Is that some kind of slang?

> "Slang" is snake in Afrikaans.

(14) What her goal was is beyond me. Anyway, she even bought khaki shorts and leather shoes for the trip.

> —

(15) Amanda, her in-law, didn't have a clue either. Was she too fed up with work?

> "Shé" is snake in Mandarin, which is hidden in "Amanda her in-law" when read out. (The OP informs me that the intended answer is "she too" or "she2", which would be the correct Mandarin word with tone numbers.)

(16) A rabid work environment can make you go nuts. That had been a problem when she was a teen.

> Nothing yet, but "a rabid" could refer to Arabic. Fun Fact #3 mentions the Arabian desert.

(17) OK, I'll just spit it out. She ended up travelling to Mexico, brother, and she died there. Ana is dead.

> "Cobra" is hidden in "Mexico, brother", when spoken. Some kinds of cobra can spit venom, hence the "spit it out".

(18) Two days had already elapsed before I was able to get to the village where she was, and her name had already been added to the obituary.

> Someone who adds names to an obituary could be a "death adder".

(19) I checked it myself. She HAD been declared dead. But yesterday I saw her outside my window at night. And this morning following me in the subway.

> "Had" is snake in Czech ("check").

(20) The cops are headed to my house right now. I can't illustrate how terrified I am Bobby. Am I going crazy Bobby? Bobby? Bobby? Bobby?

> This refers to copperheads ("Cops are headed"). "Illustrate" may refer to the patterns on the snake's back. Fun Fact #4 mentions how copperheads can hide in autumn leaves.

Comment: Excellent!! The final answer and clues #1, #3, #8, #13, #19 are completely correct, #4, #9, #17 and #18 have the important part correct, but are missing the secondary clue (but it's enough, I guess),  #15 is correct, but the whole intended word is actually "she too", which maps to "she2", which is the Mandarin word with tone numbers.

 #7 and #10 are correct for a different reason than intended (nice!).

 #11 is wrong.

Comment: #2 is correct -------

Comment: The Nadir line is supposed to welsh I think (WELL, SHe reached...) Neidr being snake in welsh. And the Asp.net line has Cleopatra hidden in it for the second part of the clue (ExaCLTY A PATROn)

Comment: Thanks.I've numbered the lines for easier reference. And I've added your answer, @Timoris.

Comment: #11 is now correct, as is the Cleopatra reference.

Comment: #6 is correct. For the sake of clarity, boa is the feminine singular, which grammatically agrees with história (= story).

Comment: Thanks. But the story could also be a (masculine) _conto_, and the reference is only carried over from the previous line, which is hard to notice when you solve the clues individually. It's a nice detail, but not crucial.

Comment: #20 might refer to Australian ("can't illustrate") copperheads ("cops are headed")

Comment: You got it! Good job.

Do you want me to tell you the missing clues right now, or do you want some extra time to try and figure them out (or let other people try)?

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you can wait a bit before revealing the missing parts. The fun facts have only been out for an hour or so and weekends are slow. I'm at my wit's end right now, but others can have a go at the remaining clues. If you like you can show your intended solutions in a separate answer.

Comment: @M Oehm, weekend's over, it's time to reveal the missing clues :) #5 is Hellene in "Hell, lean" (Greek), the modern Greek word for snake is φίδι, hidden in (coffee, the [absurd]); fun fact 2 relates to this. #7 is really Latin, but the intended word was "creeping", which in Latin is "serpens" and also means snake. The connection in #10 was just that Delphi is where the mythical Python lived. Your guess is much better than what I intended though, and I still can't believe I missed that! #12 is Japan ("did you panic", which requires a pronunciation with yod coalescence (fun fact 1) [...]

Comment: [...]), snake in Japanese is hebi, which is pronounced with a bilabial fricative, making it sound similar to "heavy". #14 is a species, the water moccasin. "Water" is hidden in "what her" and moccasin is the "leather [...] shoes"; fun fact 4 was also about this. #16 is really Arabic; as suggested by fun fact #3, you had to use the plural for snake, ṯaʿābīn, which roughly corresponds to "that had been". This was by far the hardest clue, since it required a deep look into Arabic inflection and pronunciation, and even then the connection was hard to see. #18 has "elapid" in "elapsed".

Comment: Thanks for revealing and clarifying the clues. I had seen the Hellenic reference, but couldn't find the word. I wondered whether there was a language called Upanic. Your linguistic knowledge is impressive, but probably over most peoples' heads. The accuracy you've put into the foreign words -- boa is feminine; bilabial fricatives; tone numbers in Mandarin etc. -- is lost on most puzzlers who, like me, will have to resort to Google translate or Wiktionary.

Comment: Buf, if you allow me a bit of criticism, I find many of the English homophones rather unconvincing. (Then again, I'm not very good at listening to or speaking English.) And the clues suffer from being inconsistent. Sometimes, a type of snake is hinted at. Sometimes, a language is hidden somewhere (but at other times, it is just a country -- I'm sure I would have found "Japanese"), but the snake reference is either (a) one of the words; (b) hidden between words or (c) the translation of an English word into that language.

Comment: This is a super puzzle idea, but in my opinion, it would have worked better with fewer, but consistent clues. For what it's worth, the first clue I got was the African slang. When I found out that snake in Czech is had, I knew I was onto something.

Comment: @MOehm, thanks. I'll keep this in mind when I create my next puzzle; this was my first ever and I'm glad someone bothered to try it. The need to use extra resources was intentional, as I am well aware that no one speaks this many languages (in fact, I used the very page you linked to when I was writing it up). I was also aware that some clues were excessively difficult. Four of them in particular: Greek, Portuguese, Australian and especially Arabic. That's the reason why I decided to accept an answer with four clues missing. You figured out two of the hard ones, that's something to be proud of